# Gun clipping through arm during third-person animation

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

I have been setting up a Blend Tree for motion animation in Unity. I'm using Root Motion for now. I parented the gun to the root of the player and then I use `OnAnimatorIK` to lock the two hands in position.

The overall looks and feel is great by my standards. The only thing I am disappointed about is the butt of the gun clips through the character's upper arm when running.

[image: Gun butt problem]

Is there a way to crop this in the game? I'd like to avoid going into a 3d Editor and making it two separate meshes which I could then I guess somehow disable. I'm hoping there is a better way to handle this situation.

Also I wonder if the gun being parented to the Root player object is wise. I had tried parenting to the 'right-hand' bone but this made the gun point upwards about 45° and looked silly.

Comment: It looks like moving the gun position a little further forward when running would fix the visible clipping from this angle, *and* look more correct from other angles if this character can ever be seen from the side (eg. in a cutscene, replay, etc. even if you have no multiplayer)

Comment: @DMGregory FYI: I am using Microsoft Edge (brand new install) and I get hefty crash/black screen inside of Edge only when using this website and only when i try to post my question and/or answer. It does not happen during comment posts or on any other website

Comment: I haven't experienced that on Edge in my use of the site. [It sounds like a bug to report to the StackExchange team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) or to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Basically thanks to DM Gregory's help, I have managed to fix it very simply.

I already had a 'pivot' object as a parent to my Gun. This itself is child directly of players root.

All I had to do was drag its local position forwards a little and it stopped the problem. In doing this I noticed dragging it upwards also looked a little better. Now it looks pretty great in all animations. Not perfect but decent enough for my first try at making such animations.

Hope this helps someone in future.